# How to iterate over the namespaces in the metafields using shopify liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

In the "product.liquid" template, I want to expose all the metafields to my javascript code.  Right now I have a namespace called "mystuff", so I did this...

```
// Copy all the METAFIELDS into the meta object
let meta = {
    global: {{ product.metafields.global | json }},
    mystuff: {{ product.metafields.mystuff | json }}
};
```

and this works. However, it requires me to know in advance all the namespaces and list them one per line.  Can I get the list of namespaces programmatically, like this?

```
let meta = {
    {% for ns in product.metafields.namespaces %}
        {{ ns.name }} : {{ ns | json }},
    {% endfor %}
};
```

I tried, but this does not work.  Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Step back one level and iterate just Metafields, and you might be able to see the ones you are allowed to see. I believe as App developers we can finally hide our own Metafield namespaces from prying eyes, so YMMV here.

Note that your code trying to turn this result into JSON is not recommended either. Instead, get the namespace Metafields, iterate them, and each will have a type, key and value. You get JSON values too in some fields.

Answer (score 0):

So the simple way to loop through all the metafields is here:

CONDITIONS
To loop through metafields, you should keep the same namespace, by default Shopify sets "custom" namespace to all metafields. You can keep anything while creating a metafield.
Let's assume we will loop through all the metafields with the namespace added as "option", so we have `product.metafields.option.KEY`.

```
{% for metafield in product.metafields.option %}
 {% assign key = metafield[0] %}
 {% assign type = product.metafields.option[key].type %}

<!--// Now you got the meta-field's KEY & TYPE, handle it according to its access syntax; for example below, I am printing text of type text-multiline(list.single_line_text_field) meta-field values -->

 {% assign values = product.metafields.option[key].value %}
  {% for value in values %}
   {{ value }}
  {% endfor %}

 {% endfor %}
```